# Wordpress Theme for Video Showcase

Tags: themes, theme-recommendation

Does anyone know of a good theme for showcasing multiple Youtube videos? Thanks!

Comment: @Ambitious Amoeba - Not helpful. @jas225 was asking for a specific recommendation not to be told where to find a list of themes which is the same reason people read Consumer Reports instead of just googling for *"Cars."*  See: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300/is-there-any-way-to-ignore-a-user-in-se/305#305

Comment: @jas225 - Sorry if you might be getting a negative opinion of WordPress Answers. I would give you a recommendation if I only had experience with your needs. Hopefully someone else will give you a recommendation that meets your needs.

Comment: @jas255: Could you give some more specific requirements? There are many themes out there that do *something* with video, but maybe you had some specific features in mind? Examples of sites (even non-WordPress) you like?

Comment: @Mike: I agree, and lmgtfy links are even [blocked on the main Stack Overflow for this reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links).

Comment: thanks to those of you who understand the condescending nature of Ambitious Amoeba's response. I know how to use Google, I was hoping to leverage the communities experience with WP to find the best one.

Comment: @mikeschinkel @jan fabry I think I have found what I am looking for. I appreciate the responses.

Comment: **@jas225** Please either post your solution or accept one of the posted solutions.  This will improve your 25% acceptance rate and help anyone else who has this or a similar question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually recommend a hybrid approach - take a good theme for showcasing photos and substitute in your YouTube videos.

Photo themes give you large portions of screen real estate for imagery, and if you do it right it's not difficult to substitute an embedded object (i.e. YouTube video) for the images.

Some good ones to start with:

- [Aperture](http://www.woothemes.com/2009/04/aperture/) by WooThemes
- [Landscape](http://www.studiopress.com/themes/landscape) by StudioPress

Alternatively, you can also find some pretty good video-specific themes that will take less work to rebuild and redesign:

- [WooTube](http://www.woothemes.com/2009/01/wootube/) - a YouTube clone by WooThemes
- [WordTube](http://wparchive.com/wordtube-video-wordpress-theme/) - another YouTube clone
- [Video themes](http://www.themegarden.com/category/themes/by-category/video/) by ThemeGarden

Answer (score 1):

This theme probably suits your needs.

http://www.themeflash.com/free-podcasting-video-and-photography-wordpress-theme/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Videopress.com](http://Videopress.com) which is developed by the creators of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I just used this theme and love it! It's not free but it's cheap.

http://themeforest.net/item/wave-a-video-centric-theme-for-wordpress/45855